# Laravel VueJS Form method vs Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm creating an App using Laravel for the backend and VueJs for the frontend.

I was wondering what is actually more correct for updating a row from my database:

1. Creating a method="POST" form that executes a Controller function.
2. Just making a few inputs with a button that when is clicked calls a function that makes an axios request to my backend.

Comment: Are you using InertiaJS?

Comment: No I'm not using it

Comment: I recommend using InertiaJS, it will save you hours on trivial things like this trust me, plus it has great sources so you can learn in pretty easily!